# Why is this delegate not triggering is a mystery

Tags: ios, delegates, uialertview

I have developed this class that is basically a UIAlertView with an input field that runs on blocks. So, whatever the user does on the alertView (click cancel, ok, or fill the text), returns to a block:

**HEADER**

```
typedef void (^onClickBlock)(NSInteger buttonIndex, NSString *textoInput);


@interface AlertViewBlocoComInput : NSObject

- (void)mostrarAlertViewBlocoComTitulo:(NSString *)titulo
                              mensagem:(NSString *)mensagem
                     tituloBotaoCancel:(NSString *)tituloCancel
                     outrosBotoesArray:(NSArray *)titulosOutrosBotoes
                   inputComPlaceHolder:(NSString *)textoPlaceholder
                      comBlocoExecucao:(onClickBlock)bloco;

@end
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
@interface AlertComBloco : UIAlertView
@property (nonatomic, copy) onClickBlock runOnClickBlock;
@end


@implementation AlertComBloco
@end


@interface AlertViewBlocoComInput () <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end


@implementation AlertViewBlocoComInput 


- (void)mostrarAlertViewBlocoComTitulo:(NSString *)titulo
                              mensagem:(NSString *)mensagem
                     tituloBotaoCancel:(NSString *)tituloCancel
                     outrosBotoesArray:(NSArray *)titulosOutrosBotoes
                   inputComPlaceHolder:(NSString *)textoPlaceholder
                      comBlocoExecucao:(onClickBlock)bloco

{

  AlertComBloco *alerta = [[AlertComBloco alloc] initWithTitle:titulo
                                                       message:mensagem
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:tituloCancel
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
  alerta.runOnClickBlock =bloco;

  // adicionar os outros botões
  for (NSString *umOutroBotao in titulosOutrosBotoes) {
    [alerta addButtonWithTitle:umOutroBotao];
  }


  [alerta setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
  UITextField *input = [alerta textFieldAtIndex:0];
  input.placeholder = textoPlaceholder;

  [alerta show];

}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

  AlertComBloco *alerta = (AlertComBloco *)alertView;
  onClickBlock bloco = alerta.runOnClickBlock;

  UITextField *input = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

  if (bloco) {
    bloco(buttonIndex, input.text);
  }

}


@end
```

I run it, it shows the alertView with the message, placeholder, perfect. I click cancel or fill the text and press ok and the `alertview:clickedButtonAtIndex:` is never triggered. I am not seeing why.

thanks

Comment: Does AlertComBloco override any methods of UIAlertView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown us how you're calling this but most likely your `AlertViewBlocoComInput` is a local variable that has fallen out of scope and is therefore deallocated before the user completes their input. You can demonstrate this by temporarily adding a `dealloc` method that will tell you when the object is deallocated.

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

In terms of fixing this, you could make your `AlertViewBlocoComInput` instance a class property, so it won't be released until you manually `nil` it. Or you can make `AlertViewBlocoComInput` maintain a strong reference to itself until `clickedButtonAtIndex` is called.

Or, easiest, leverage the fact that `UIAlertView` already retains itself, so you can retire `AlertComBloco` altogether, folding it into `AlertViewBlocoComInput`:

```
typedef void (^onClickBlock)(NSInteger buttonIndex, NSString *textoInput);

@interface AlertViewBlocoComInput : UIAlertView <UIAlertViewDelegate>

- (instancetype)initComTitulo:(NSString *)titulo
                     mensagem:(NSString *)mensagem
            tituloBotaoCancel:(NSString *)tituloCancel
            outrosBotoesArray:(NSArray *)titulosOutrosBotoes
          inputComPlaceHolder:(NSString *)textoPlaceholder
             comBlocoExecucao:(onClickBlock)bloco;

@property (nonatomic, copy) onClickBlock runOnClickBlock;

@end

@implementation AlertViewBlocoComInput

- (instancetype)initComTitulo:(NSString *)titulo
                     mensagem:(NSString *)mensagem
            tituloBotaoCancel:(NSString *)tituloCancel
            outrosBotoesArray:(NSArray *)titulosOutrosBotoes
          inputComPlaceHolder:(NSString *)textoPlaceholder
             comBlocoExecucao:(onClickBlock)bloco

{
    self = [super initWithTitle:titulo message:mensagem delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:tituloCancel otherButtonTitles:nil];

    if (self) {
        self.runOnClickBlock =bloco;

        // adicionar os outros botões
        for (NSString *umOutroBotao in titulosOutrosBotoes) {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:umOutroBotao];
        }

        [self setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
        UITextField *input = [self textFieldAtIndex:0];
        input.placeholder = textoPlaceholder;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (self.runOnClickBlock) {
        UITextField *input = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        self.runOnClickBlock(buttonIndex, input.text);
    }
}

@end
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
AlertViewBlocoComInput *obj = [[AlertViewBlocoComInput alloc] initComTitulo:@"title" mensagem:@"message" tituloBotaoCancel:@"OK" outrosBotoesArray:nil inputComPlaceHolder:@"Placeholder" comBlocoExecucao:^(NSInteger buttonIndex, NSString *textoInput) {
    // do whatever you want with `buttonIndex` and `textoInput` here
    //
    // NSLog(@"%ld %@", (long)buttonIndex, textoInput);
}];
[obj show];
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that this could be the case but then I thought about other things and forgot to test that. THANKS, you are awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can directly subclass UIAlertView and add your own initializer. I have abstracted your classes to a single subclass of UIAlertView and it works fine. Please see my posts below,

```
typedef void (^onClickBlock)(NSInteger buttonIndex, NSString *textoInput);

@interface AlertComBloco : UIAlertView<UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, copy) onClickBlock runOnClickBlock;
@end


@implementation AlertComBloco


- (id)initWithTitulo:(NSString *)titulo mensagem:(NSString*)mensagem tituloBotaoCancel:(NSString*)tituloCancel outrosBotoesArray:(NSArray *)titulosOutrosBotoes inputComPlaceHolder:(NSString *)textoPlaceholder
    comBlocoExecucao:(onClickBlock)bloco{
  if(self = [self initWithTitle:titulo message:mensagem delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:tituloCancel otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]){
    _runOnClickBlock = bloco;
    for (NSString *umOutroBotao in titulosOutrosBotoes) {
      [self addButtonWithTitle:umOutroBotao];
    }
    [self setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    UITextField *input = [self textFieldAtIndex:0];
    input.placeholder = textoPlaceholder;

  }
  return self;
}



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

  UITextField *input = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

  if (self.runOnClickBlock) {
    self.runOnClickBlock(buttonIndex, input.text);
  }

}

@end
```

Then, you could call it with the block in your view controller just like this,

```
- (void)showAlert:(id)sender{
  AlertComBloco *alertCombo = [[AlertComBloco alloc] initWithTitulo:@"Hi" mensagem:@"Custom Alert" tituloBotaoCancel:@"Cancel" outrosBotoesArray:@[@"Other"] inputComPlaceHolder:@"Placeholder" comBlocoExecucao:^(NSInteger buttonIndex, NSString *textoInput) {
    NSLog(@"Button at index %ld, with text %@", (long)buttonIndex, textoInput);
  }];
  [alertCombo show];
}
```